# For react-virtualized Masonry what's the recommended way of handling deleting of items?

Tags: reactjs, masonry, react-virtualized

**https://codesandbox.io/s/l79vn4rowq**

When deleting items, I am not reinitializing the cellMeasurerCache, as I already have the dimensions of each item. By doing so, the upper and lower bound for populating position cache is not set as the CellMeasurer doesn't invoke `invalidateCellSizeAfterRender` if the dimensions are already present in the cache.

```
      //hack to set a range for populating position cache
      masonryInstance.invalidateCellSizeAfterRender({ rowIndex: 0 });
      masonryInstance.invalidateCellSizeAfterRender({
        rowIndex: batchSize - 1
      });

      //populate position cache
      masonryInstance.recomputeCellPositions();
```

I had to use the hack method `invalidateCellSizeAfterRender` for setting the upper and lower bounds for populating position cache. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with the `Masonry` component. What you're describing sounds like it might be a bug in `Masonry`. All that I would expect you to need to do is call `masonryInstance.clearCellPositions()` after updating your position cache, but it doesn't look like that's sufficient.